# Valid file path, Path.GetFullPath and Core

Tags: c#, .net-core

In .Net Framework one easy way to test if a file path is validly formatted is to use Path.GetFullPath. This method throws an exception if you pass it an invalidly formatted path.

```
public static bool IsValidFilePath(string filepath)
{
    try
    {
        Path.GetFullPath(filepath);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

In Core 3.1 this isn't the case. As can be demonstrated by the code below. .Net framework would throw on the Path.GetFullPath. This code makes it to File.Create in Core were File.Create throws an exception.

```
    string tmp = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), ":");
    Path.GetFullPath(tmp);
    File.Create(tmp);
```

The 3.1 document for Path.GetFullPath says Path.GetTempPath should be generating an exception for the above.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getfullpath?view=netcore-3.1

> [NotSupportedException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.notsupportedexception?view=netcore-3.1)
>  `path` contains a colon (":") that is not part of a volume identifier (for example, "c:\").

Note that this isn't the only invalid path Path.GetFullPath is not generating an exception for. Seems like a Core bug.  How can I log this issue with MS.  Second any suggested workarounds.   Using

```
        if (filepath.IndexOfAny(Path.GetInvalidPathChars()) >= 0)
            return false;
```

Does better but doesn't catch all of the cases - paths containing a badly placed ":" being one of them.

Comment: .NETFramework was quite hard-ass about it.  Necessarily so, it needed to screen paths up front to ensure that CAS could work.  But that stopped being relevant, first at v4.0 when CAS got deprecated.  Lots more reasons beyond that, ":" is important to access NTFS streams for example.  And the ultimate neckshot, the unixes have no rules.  Today it is like Obama's view on foreign policy, don't do stupid sh*t.  Wise words.